# How to unpack 2, 2 and 3 bits out of a byte

Tags: go, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Assuming I have 3 bytes (2x2bits and 1x3bits) packed like this:

```
func pack(a, b, c byte) byte { // is there a more efficient way to pack them?
    return a<<6 | b<<4 | c
}

func main() {
    v := pack(1, 2, 6)
    a := v >> 6
    b := v >> 4 // wrong
    c := v & 7
    fmt.Println(v, a, b, c)
}
```

How do I unpack `b`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to mask off the unused bits like you've already done for `c`. I also added masks to the pack function, to prevent accidental overlapping of values:

```
const (
    threeBits = 0x7
    twoBits   = 0x3
)

func pack(a, b, c byte) byte {
    return a<<6 | b&twoBits<<4 | c&threeBits
}

func main() {
    v := pack(1, 2, 6)
    a := v >> 6
    b := v >> 4 & twoBits
    c := v & threeBits
    fmt.Println(v, a, b, c)
}
```

Comment: The mask is also always the highest allowed value specified by the field width, e.g. 2 bit wide field => mask is 3.